# continuous left join with same join key cause unbalanced tasks among executors in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

environment:

```
spark2.4.0
spark on yarn with 100 executors
spark.executor.memory           4g
spark.driver.memory             3g
spark.executor.cores            1
```

I execute a sql with seven continuous left join with the same join key like following:

```
create table tmp.res as select * from 
  A a
  left join B b
     on a.id = b.id
  left join C c
     on a.id = c.id
  left join D d
     on a.id = d.id
  ...
```

And i found tasks are unbalanced among executors which cause some task fetch block from hot executor failed.

I think each left join will shuffle many records to the same executor because of data locality(the same join key).

So i guess because of the same join key tasks skew become more and more serious as each join running. Eventually, the hot executor become unreachable and application crashed.

Am i right?

[image]

error log:

```
 ERROR ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from
```

Comment: Are the `id` unique?

Comment: yes, id is uniq and not null